# How to add class in parent div of iframe when you clicked inside that iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four frame in one page and each iframe has its own content and parent div with some class in it

Below is the screen shot for that page:

Requirements: In Every panel there are some links, when you click on these links its call some other page using AJAX you can see in second image.

Below is HTML Code:

```
<div class="north-center border">
    <div class="linksDetails">
        <div class="panelLinks">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('fxtraders.html', 'panel1');">FX Traders</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('fxcharting.html', 'panel1');">Fx Charting</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('fxbonds.html', 'panel1');">FI Inventory (Bonds)</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('fxwatcher.html', 'panel1');">FX RATE WATCHER</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="open-row-box" id="panel1"></div>
</div>
```

Links screen are comming under (linksDetails class) when user click on any link then i m adding new class with name (hidelinks) in this same div and make it display none

So how can i hide my content panel when i clicked on cross icon on top of every panel means when i clicked on that cross icon which is inside iframe i only want to add hidelink class to its parent divs which again hide content div and show this links div again.

i can hide only first panel using this jqyery code but not each panel.

Jquery Code:

```
    $(window).load(function(){

// Through this i m adding and removing hide links:

$(".panelLinks a").click(function(){
$(this).parents().eq(2).parent().removeClass("hideLinks");
$(this).parents().eq(2).parent().addClass("hideLinks");
});

// Through this i can only add hidelinks class for first panel only not for each panel seperately:


$("a.close").on('click', function() {
$("#mainFrame", window.parent.document).parent().parent().children().removeClass('hideLinks');
});
});
```

Main Reqirement:

How can i hide my content panel seperately like when i click on first panel cross icon its hide only first panel, when i click on second panel its hide only second panel like this?

Thanks  in Advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can get the parent of an iframe

```
var parent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
```